# Code commit repository cloning issue in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codecommit

I am trying to create a repository in AWS Code-commit, i am able to create the repository but i am not able to clone github code into this created new repository.

This is the code i am using to create a repository

```
resource "aws_codecommit_repository" "test" {
  repository_name = "MyTestRepository"
  description     = "This is the Sample App Repository"
}
```

i also want to clone a github repo into this new code-commit repo.

Here is the terraform code-commit page link for documentation https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/codecommit_repository

Comment: How do you clone the repo?

Comment: yeah that is what i want to achieve how do i clone a github repo into this newly created repository .

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is essentially "migrate" a GitHub repo to CodeCommit. This is documented in AWS docs [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-migrate-repository-existing.html) and basically involves locally cloning source git repo and pushing to CodeCommit.

To "seed" the initial code automatically, CloudFormation has a construct `Code` in resource `AWS::CodeCommit::Repository` [2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codecommit-repository.html#cfn-codecommit-repository-code) which can copy initial code from an S3 bucket, unfortunately such an option does not seem to exist in Terraform's `aws_codecommit_repository` resource [3](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/codecommit_repository).